# reduce light reflection to model in threejs

Tags: threejs-editor

i am using MeshPhysicalMaterial

```
roughness = 1
metalness = 0
reflectivity = 0
lightMapIntensity = 0
clearcoat = 0
specularIntensity = 0
```

I don't know what else is there to reduce the light reflections on the model. I want it as real as possible.

[image]